# C言語のコンパイルへの出力について

Tags: c

下記の課題に対して「例外がスローされました」との表示が出てしまい、コンパイルに出力がされない状態です。
どなたか修正点を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

コンソールからパラメータを受け取り、ログを実行時間の昇順/降順に並べ替えて
コンソールに表示する
例）ASC を入力

```
2015/04/26 10:20:00, 5 + 6, 11
2015/04/27 14:30:51, 7 - 6, 1
2015/04/27 15:30:00, 7 + 8, 15
2015/04/28 14:30:51, 8 + 9, 17
```

例）DESC を入力

```
2015/04/28 14:30:51, 8 + 9, 17
2015/04/27 15:30:00, 7 + 8, 15
2015/04/27 14:30:51, 7 - 6, 1
2015/04/26 10:20:00, 5 + 6, 11
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp_u(const void* a, const void* d) {
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)d;
}

int cmp_d(const void* a, const void* d) {
    return *(int*)d - *(int*)a;
}

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    char op;
    float answer;
    int r,i;
    FILE* fp;
    char a[11];
    char sin[9];
    char ad;

    fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ファイルオープン失敗\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    while (1) {
        r = scanf("%d%c%d", &num1, &op, &num2);
        if (r != 3) {
            puts("input error");
            return 1;
        }

        if (op == '+') {
            answer = num1 + num2;
        }
        else if (op == '-') {
            answer = num1 - num2;
        }
        else if (op == '*') {
            answer = num1 * num2;
        }
        else if (op == '/') {
            answer = (float)num1 / num2;
        }

        time_t t = time(NULL);
        struct tm* tm = localtime(&t);
        printf("%d/%02d/%02d ", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday);
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d ", tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
        printf("%d%c%d,%f\n", num1, op, num2, answer);
        fprintf(fp, "%d/%02d/%02d ", tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday);
        fprintf(fp, "%02d:%02d:%02d ", tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
        fprintf(fp, "%d%c%d,%f\n", num1, op, num2, answer);

        printf("計算を続けますか？");
        scanf("%s\n", &a);
        if (strcmp(a, "no") == 0) {
            break ;
        }
    }
        fclose(fp);

        printf("ASC or DESC: ");
        scanf(" %s", &ad);

        if (strcmp(a, "no") == 0) {
            qsort(sin, 9, sizeof(int), cmp_u);
        }
        else {
            qsort(sin, 9, sizeof(int), cmp_d);
        }


        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", sin[i]);
        }
    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: C言語には例外は存在しません。「例外がスローされました」というエラーメッセージ事態おかしな話です。ご自身の使用されている言語を把握できていますか？

Comment: @sayuri さん、IDEの種類など環境によっては「例外」の文言が使われています。VS2022だと`例外がスローされました`というタイトルを持った吹き出し型ウインドウで中に`Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ad' was corrupted.`と表示されます。とは言えそれはコンパイル時ではなくデバッグ実行時ですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSやコンパイラ・IDE等に何を使っているのか分かりませんが、例えばデバッグモードでコンパイルした結果をデバッグ実行などしてみれば、もう少し詳細なエラーメッセージ等が表示されるはずですので、それを基に調べたり直したり出来るでしょう。

今回の件では、抜粋した以下の部分で、3文字または4文字＋終端の`\0`で5文字以上の領域を用意しておかなければならない所を1文字分しか定義していないことで発生しているものでしょう。

```
    char ad;

        printf("ASC or DESC: ");
        scanf(" %s", &ad);
```

該当の`ad`の定義を、1つのcharではなく5文字以上のcharの配列として定義すれば例外は発生しなくなるでしょう。

```
    char ad[5];

        printf("ASC or DESC: ");
        scanf(" %s", &ad);
```

---

ただし、提示されたプログラムソースコードでは、ログファイルを読み取り・ソート・表示する部分は未完成(ほぼ作られていない)状態ですので、まだまだ先は長いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございました。